# How to properly deploy a customer record script with NetSuite's suiteScript?

Tags: deployment, netsuite, suitescript

Currently I'm writing an example script to get the hang of the suiteScript environment and get a better idea of how it all works.  Right now I've written a script that looks like it should create and save a new customer record upon deployment.  I dont run into any errors loading the script into NetSuite and I put the code through a debugger and the syntax seems right.

'''

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
 define(["N/record"], function (r) {
    function creatCustomer() {
      var customer = record.create({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
        isDynamic: false,
        defaultValues: null
      });
      customer.setValue(
        {fieldId: "firstname", value: "James", ignoreFieldChange: false},
        {fieldId: "lastname", value: "Halpert"},
        {fieldId: "subsidiary",value: "Training 7"},
        {fieldId: "email", value: "JHalpert@DM.com"},
        {fieldId: "company Name",value: "Dunder Mifflin Test"}
        );

      customer.save({
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
      });
    }
    return {
      saveRecord: creatCustomer
    };
  });
```

'''

I think the problem might be deployment, but I don't know exactly what it could be.  The script gets deployed but I can't find the customer record anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Netsuite help to read about script types and script type entry points. In particular client scripts are not generally used the way you have set that up.

This question has almost nothing in it regarding script deployment issues. (I'd expect to see at least one screen shot of the deployment screen)

For what you have written each time one of the deployment target records is saved a new customer record save will be attempted.

However the script you posted will error because:

- the subsidiary value should be the internalid of the subsidiary - not the subsidiary name.
- you are declaring 'N/record' as `function(r)` but then using it like `record.create`
- record.setValue doesn't take a list of fieldId/value pairs

It may error if the user submitting the record doesn't have permissions to create customers.
It will likely error the second time it runs because a non-unique user name is being  given. (Though this depends on how your account is configured)

One way to 'play' with scripts is to open a console window on any record in edit mode (and for some other screens) and you can run individual scripts like:

```js
require(["N/record"], function (record) {
  var customer = record.create({
    type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
    isDynamic: false,
    defaultValues: null
  });
  customer.setValue({fieldId: "firstname", value: "James"}); //, ignoreFieldChange: false}, <- this is for dynamic mode and client scripts
  customer.setValue({fieldId: "lastname", value: "Halpert"});
  customer.setValue({fieldId: "subsidiary",value: "Training 7"});
  customer.setValue({fieldId: "email", value: "JHalpert@DM.com"});
  customer.setValue({fieldId: "company Name",value: "Dunder Mifflin Test"});  

  var custId = customer.save({
    enableSourcing: true,
    ignoreMandatoryFields: false
  });
  console.log('created customer ', custId);
});
```